# How can I access the user's environment variables on osx with java?

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to run livestreamer in my java app but it looks like java is using the default $PATH instead of the user's. The reason I know this is executing `echo %PATH`is different from the terminal vs java. Is there a way to force java to use the user's PATH?

**Terminal**

```
zs-Mac:~ z$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**Java Jar**

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: How do you run you app?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()

Comment: @talex by double clicking a jar.

Comment: @AshFrench I tried that but the PATH is still generic

Comment: So you set path in console and then doubleclick jar? Console have no relation to you jar. Try `java -jar youjar.jar` from console.

Comment: @talex I don't set the PATH. See edited op

Comment: Then who set it? Maybe there is some starting script who did that? And did you tried to run your app from console?

Comment: @talex must've been python when i installed python3. it does work when ran from terminal but it is easier just to double click the jar

Comment: You better ask this question in other stackexchange site which specialize on osx. This is obviously not java problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is `osx` related problem.

Comment: @talex how is this as osx-only issue?

Comment: Because there is specific to os how it is `PATH` setted up and how it is inherited from one process to another.